# How to add modelforms dynamically?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple use case. 
I have 3 models foo, foo1 and foo2. I have created model forms for them. 
Now in a page I have these forms together on that page.

**PROBLEM :**  The user has the option to click on a "ADD" button. Once he clicks on it he will be able to add 1 more foo2 i.e. 1 more foo2 form will open or be displayed. How should I do this ? i.e. how do I add a modelform dynamically ?

Edit:

This can be done using jquery. But my question is how do I differentiate it in the view ? Should I use prefix ? i.e. should I add dynamic prefix to the forms that are being created ?

Comment: javascript, ie jQuery...

Comment: You need to use formsets and some javascript. There are lot of examples on this site as well as elsewhere.

Comment: I looked into this recently and had trouble submitting the forms altogether when they were dynamically inserted with jQuery. I solved it by having each form's submit reference the next form. IT gets the desired effect but makes you change pages consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rohan says in the comments, if you have more than one of the same kind of form on a page, you should be using formsets. Each form within the formset has its own prefix which includes an ID which you can simply increment with your Javascript.